# convert "1 hour and 10 minutes" into 01:10:00 in php

Tags: php, date

How to convert "1 hour and 10 minutes" string into the following format 01:10:00 using php. This is what i did - `echo  date('H:i:s',strtotime('1 hour and 10 min'));`
Output is -- `01:00:00`

Comment: are `hour`, `and` and `min` always there?

Comment: yeah string contains hours and min always

Comment: so it could be hour or hours? depending on whether hour is > 1?

Comment: now i changed the code to -date('H:i:s',strtotime('7 hour and 10 min')); and the output is -- 01:00:00 :(

Comment: Hours min are not fixed, in some strings I only have hours and in some only mins are specified.

Comment: Then there's no easy way to do this, you need to do regex to match different types of inputs, or split etc. Even then, if your string specification changes even a bit, you need to add more implementation... I suggest, if you can help it, change the input format to something more parsable

Comment: Is there _anything_ fixed in the string? I guess that even "hour" can be "hours" and "minutes" can be "minute" or "min" or maybe even "min." But even though it _is_ possible to solve. You just need to precisely specify your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$time = '1 hour and 10 min';

$arr = explode( ' ', $time);

if ( count($arr) > 2) {
 echo date( 'H:i:s', strtotime($arr[0] . ':' . $arr[count($arr)-2]));
} else {
    echo $arr[1] == 'hour' ? date( 'H:i:s', strtotime($arr[0] . ':' . '00')):
    date( 'H:i:s', strtotime(00 . ':' . $arr[0]));
}
```

Comment: This code is not working for -- $time = '7 hour'; hours min are not fixed, in some strings I only have hours and in some only mins are specified

Comment: Sorry but you said min and hours were always there

Comment: ...and also works when you specify just min. $time='7 min' for example

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `hour` `and` `min` are *always there* (emphasize), you can use `sscanf`

```
$text = "1 hour 10 min";
list($hour, $min) = sscanf($text, "%d hour %d min");
echo 
   str_pad($hour, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . ':' . 
   str_pad($min, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . 
   ':00';
```

Comment: If i specified $text = "7 min"; output is - 07:00:00 which is wrong :(

Comment: @swapnesh 1) see my emphasize 2) your comment says `yeah string contains hours and min always` :s, in any case, you have accepted an answer :), good luck

Comment: //ohh i am very sorry 1) I was desperate for a working solution and yes i admit that i missed your emphasized string :( and for 2) i mean to say that the string is going to contains hour and min only ..very sorry but i think the number of acceptance speaks more than my acceptance :)

Answer (score 1):

```
php > preg_match('/^(\d+)\shour[^\d]+(\d+)\smin.+$/i', '1 hour and 10 minutes', $matches);
php > echo str_pad($matches[1], 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).':'.str_pad($matches[2], 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).':00';
01:10:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the examples in the [PHP documentation for the strtotime function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), it seems that it may be the word `and` that is causing you the problem.

I don't know where your input string is coming from, but is it possible to exclude the `and` (i.e. just have `1 hour 10 min`)?

Comment: yeah i can remove that "and" basically  i was searching for an easy function as this thing sounds a common stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that hours and minutes are always there (even `0 hours 0 minutes`):

```
$my_time_string = '1 hour and 10 min';
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $my_time_string, $out);
$output = sprintf('%02d:%02d:00', $out[0][0], $out[0][1]);
echo $output;
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this

$string="1 hour and 10 minutes";

echo preg_replace("/[a-z\s]+/",":",$string)."00

Comment: How does this convert the string `1 hour and 10 minutes` to `01:10:00`?

Comment: Sorry, I modified my answer. Please check this now